# I'll check we have this medicine in stock

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

Why is there no "if" or "whether" in that construction? Is that sentence correct? How common is it?

Comment: Off hand I'd say you can't drop *if* or *whether*, but you can certainly drop *that*, and *I'll check that we have this medicine in stock* makes perfect sense.

Comment: It's not "correct", in the English teacher sense.

Comment: Very common not to say 'if' or 'whether'.  Also very common to say "I'll check *to/and see if*...."

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Can anyone locate that rule in a reference grammar/usage book? Not that I don't appreciate your answers, I just suspect that it's sometimes not possible to omit these if/whether conjunctions, like.

Comment: .... "We'll see (if/whether) we have this medicine in stock" - omission possible, but

"We saw if / whether we had this medicine in stock" - past form seems dubious, or am I seeing more than there is to it.
(I am sorry that the question split.)

Comment: You can't drop *if* or *whether* full stop - the tense doesn't make any difference as far as I can see. If you take a sentence like *I didn't know she was going*, it can only mean *I didn't know* that *she was going* - even if you come up with a backstory which calls for *I didn't know* whether/if *she was going*. The original sentence does not involve dropping *whether/if*.

Comment: In British English, I see no problem at all with the questioned sentence, *at least when spoken*: the *if* or *whether* is merely elided.  But I wouldn't expect to see it *written* in that form.  I agree with Piotr's comment above about *omission possible* in certain cases; and also with the comment from @Dan, which I note is from a British perspective.

Comment: You don't need to have "if" or "whether" because you are eliding the sentence "I'll check _that_ we _do_ have this medicine in stock."

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't strictly correct for formal/written english, but its a reasonably common contraction in general use.

Including `if` would be far more common, and `whether` too, but the latter is a little more formal - more likely to be written than spoken.

Comment: Given that ellipsis is both common and permissible even in formal written English, on what basis can you say it's not "strictly correct"? NB It's not a "contraction" either (excuse the pun: *it's* **is** a contraction). Contractions involve *elision*, which is quite different from ellipsis.

Comment: @Chappo  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contraction  - `a short form of a word or combination of words that is often used instead of the full form in spoken English`

Since the OP appears to be non-native, I was trying to avoid such technical terms as elision, or confusing terms like ellipsis

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this construction is a shorter version of "I'll check **that** we have this medicine in stock".  The words "if" or "whether" cannot regularly be dropped in this kind of context, but the word "that" can be.

"I'll check we have this medicine in stock" doesn't sound *great* to me, but I wouldn't say that involves contraction or elision of either "if" or "whether".

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/check) provides the following example for the use of "check" with a *that*-clause:

> He checked that he had his room key.

Comment: +1 for “It doesn’t sound great to me”-  it sounds horrible to me. I’d certainly never say it.